# Android Content Provider SelectionArgs

Tags: android, cursor, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I'm trying to write a very basic app that reads from the contacts content provider and pulls the contacts from a specific group name. How do I set the selection arguments so that the contacts information is pulled from a specific group?

I apologize if this has been answered elsewhere. I have searched and failed to find a good example on how to set selectionArgs so sort through information.

```
private Cursor getContacts() {
    // Run query
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED + " = '"
            + ("1") + "'";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
            + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
            sortOrder);
}
```

Thanks for the help!